# Как сохранить положение radio-кнопки на сайте?

Tags: html, php, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно записать возможно через javascript активное состояние radio-кнопки в сессию, чтобы та хранилась, и при переходе на новые страницы сайта, принимала то значение, чтобы было выбрано ранее?

Comment: lampa, работает вот хранилище и кнопки, но она не сообщает скрипту сортировки о хранилище... http://yalon.su/ вот там категории, при обновлении оно запоминает radio-кнопку, но не отдаёт скрипту сортировки сообщение о активности этой radio-кнопки

Comment: сегодня с утреца постараюсь глянуть.

Comment: придумали?

Comment: @lampa, хм, заменил код, но он не работает, может я не понял, что такое jquery ready, но заменил я строку              var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type=' + $($filterType+":checked").val() + ']');

Comment: @ivanforpw ничего не нужно было заменять, а наоборот - вставить после когда. jquery ready это конструкция: 

$(function() { ... });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поэкономить серверные ресурсы и воспользоваться localstorage. При изменении чекбокса записываем в сторадж нужные данные. При обновлении страницы смотрим в сторадж и ищем нужные значения.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetData (elem) { 
    alert(elem.getAttribute('id'));
    localStorage.setItem(elem.getAttribute('name'), elem.getAttribute('id'));

    alert(localStorage.getItem(elem.getAttribute('name')));

} 
function GetData (item) { 
    return localStorage.getItem(item); 
}

/**
 * следующий код выполняется после загрузки страницы.
 */
window.onload = function() {
    /**
     * узнаем, какое значение у нас в localStorage.getItem(item)
     */
    var Item = GetData ('type');

    alert(Item);
    /**
     * если значение установлено (!undefined)
     */
    if(Item != undefined) {
        document.getElementById(Item).checked = true;
    }

}

</script>

<input type="radio" name="type" value="all" checked id='AllCheck' onchange="SetData(this);"> Все <br> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="blue" id='BlueCheck' onchange="SetData(this);"> Синий <br> 
<input type="radio" name="type" value="red" id='RedCheck' onchange="SetData(this);"> Красный <br>
```

Данный код добавьте в самый конец jquery ready

```
var $filteredData = $data.find('li[data-type='+GetData ('type')+']');

                // вызываем плагин
$applications.quicksand($filteredData, {
    duration: 800,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
});
```

Comment: помогите разобрать с js, пожалуйста, просто еще не начинал его учить, а тут нужно реализовать небольшой скрипт.
имя кнопки type

<script type="text/javascript">
function SetData {
localStorage.setItem('type', 'а как здесь записать информацию, что хранится в value?');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GetData {
var type = localStorage.getItem('type');
}
</script>

Comment: <input type=\"radio\" name=\"type\" value=\"all\" checked> Все <br>
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"type\" value=\"blue\"> Синий <br>
<input type=\"radio\" name=\"type\" value=\"red\"> Красный <br>

А дальше как задать ей положение через функцию?

Comment: обновил пост.

Comment: http://yalon.su/test.html
вроде что-то не так

Comment: ох я и долбаеб, еще одну ошибку нашел у себя. Капец. Значение, получаемое в функции GetData не возвращал. Обновил пост.

Comment: а я бы ajax'ом мучился...

Answer (score -1):

С помощью php: В начале страницы начинаешь сессию

```
 session_start();
```

Потом заносишь значение выбранной кнопки в сессию

```
$_SESSION['Ch'] = $Chbtn;
```

и далее с помощью if/case в зависимости от значения этой переменной устанавливаешь значение радио-кнопки

Comment: @lampa, добавил, посмотрите http://yalon.su/ здесь, но все равно не работает